# Клик по классу событие для extensions chrome

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

Пересмотрел много разных страниц с инфой, но так и не понял можно ли сделать расширение для chrome которое при клике на определённое поле класса выводил бы alert.
файл подключения расширения manifest.json

```
{
     "manifest_version": 2,

     "name": "Тест",
     "description": "Тест",
     "version": "1.0",

     "browser_action": {
         "default_icon": "icon.png"

     },

     "content_scripts": [
     {
       "matches": [
         "https://google.com/*"
       ],
       "js": [
         "script.js"
       ]
     }   ]
}
```

Comment: Все возможно. Что такое класс?

Comment: <div class="name></div>

Comment: Читал комментарии на сторонних сайтах, говорят что не возможно :(

Comment: Т.е. вы хотите, что бы на любом сайте при  кликие на div с классом .name и установленном расширении у Вас тригерил ивент?

Comment: @slowBro Да можно на одном, например на вк

Comment: @ВикторВасильев такое сделать можно через content.js который будет встраиваться на каждую страницу. Указывается в manifest.json

Comment: Я так пробовал не помогло, может быть конечно я не правильно встраивался. Я подключал js файл в файле manifest.json но ничего не происходило

Answer (score 0):

Укажите контент скрипт и url по который его вставить в manifest.json

```js
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>" //на всех страницах
      ],
      "js": [
        "src/inject/inject.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Это не помогло так как проблема обработки самого js, если повторюсь это в целом возможно. Сам файл подключения

Comment: расширение ставится, нету ошибки в файле манифеста? точно правильно указан путь до Вашего контент скрипта?

Comment: Да, само расширение появляется и подключается. Если нет какого файла, который указан в манифесте , расширение установить нельзя. Добавил мой файл манифеста в вопросе.

Comment: поправил ответ (урлу на которой используется)